# How to run execute test classes in parallel using testng with geb

Tags: maven, groovy, geb, testng.xml

### GoogleTest.groovy

```
import com.myCompany.pages.GooglePage
import geb.testng.GebReportingTestTrait
import geb.testng.GebTestTrait
import org.testng.annotations.*

class GoogleTest implements GebReportingTestTrait {

    @BeforeClass
    void setupClass () {
        println("GoogleTest @BeforeClass started")
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId()
        println("setupClass. Thread id is: " + id)
    }

    @Test
    void testGooglePage() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId()
        println("testGooglePage. Thread id is: " + id)
        go 'https://www.google.com/'
        at GooglePage

    }
}
```

### GebManualTest.groovy

```
import com.wellTrack.pages.GebishOrgHomePage
import com.wellTrack.pages.TheBookOfGebPage
import geb.testng.GebReportingTestTrait
import geb.testng.GebTestTrait
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass
import org.testng.annotations.Test


class GebManualTest implements GebReportingTestTrait {

    @BeforeClass
    void setupClass () {
        println("@BeforeClass started.")
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId()
        println("setupClass. Thread id is: " + id)
    }

    @Test
    void testCanGoGebManual() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId()
        println("testCanGoToLoginPage. Thread id is: " + id)

        to GebishOrgHomePage
        GebishOrgHomePage gebishOrgHomePage = page
        gebishOrgHomePage.manualsMenu.open()

        //first link is for the current manual
        assert manualsMenu.links[0].text().startsWith("current")

        manualsMenu.links[0].click()
        at TheBookOfGebPage
    }
}
```

### testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test-class Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2" >
    <!--<listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.example.listeners.TestListener"/>
    </listeners>-->

<test name="Test-class test" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.myCompany.tests.GebManualTest"/>
        <class name="com.myCompany.tests.GoogleTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I would like to run all the methods in the same class in the same thread (although in the above example, I only have 1 method per class), but each class will be run in a separate thread.

The above configuration does not seem to be working, the methods are run sequentially in the same thread. Is there anything wrong with the above configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I figured why this was not working. I was missing `cacheDriverPerThread = true` in my `GebConfig.groovy`. After setting this, tests are running in parallel.